# How to position <hr> in a DIV

Tags: html, css

How to put the line `<hr>` about 15 px above the bottom of the text block somewhere between button and bottom textblock?

```css
.box {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  position: relative
}

.space {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .button {
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <img class="box" src="https://d2f0ora2gkri0g.cloudfront.net/e4/16/e4164876-1967-4303-9a57-aae00eb2b22b.png" alt="oproeien" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px">

  <h2 class="space">Amsterdam</h2>

  <p class="space">Amsterdam is de (titulaire) hoofdstad en naar inwonertal de grooteeuw tot stadsuitbreidingen, waaronder de laatste grachten van de fortificatie die nu als grachtengordel bekend is en in 2010 is toegevoegd aan de UNESCO-Werelderfgoedlijst.</p>

  <a class="button" href="https://www.buienradar.nl">Slecht weer</a>

  <hr>

</div>
```

Comment: You mean you want the <hr> to be between the <p> and the <a>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<hr> Line appearing below relative div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286364/hr-line-appearing-below-relative-div)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply border on text that you can easily control with padding:

```css
.box {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  position: relative
}

.space {
  padding: 15px;

}
p.space {
   border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .button {
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <img class="box" src="https://d2f0ora2gkri0g.cloudfront.net/e4/16/e4164876-1967-4303-9a57-aae00eb2b22b.png" alt="oproeien" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px">

  <h2 class="space">Amsterdam</h2>

  <p class="space">Amsterdam is de (titulaire) hoofdstad en naar inwonertal de grooteeuw tot stadsuitbreidingen, waaronder de laatste grachten van de fortificatie die nu als grachtengordel bekend is en in 2010 is toegevoegd aan de UNESCO-Werelderfgoedlijst.</p>

  <a class="button" href="https://www.buienradar.nl">Slecht weer</a>


</div>
```

And if you want to control the width of the line you can consider a linear-gradient trick (or pseudo-element):

```css
.box {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  position: relative
}

.space {
  padding: 15px;

}
p.space {
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent calc(100% - 1px),#000 0) 0 0/50% 100% no-repeat;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .button {
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <img class="box" src="https://d2f0ora2gkri0g.cloudfront.net/e4/16/e4164876-1967-4303-9a57-aae00eb2b22b.png" alt="oproeien" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px">

  <h2 class="space">Amsterdam</h2>

  <p class="space">Amsterdam is de (titulaire) hoofdstad en naar inwonertal de grooteeuw tot stadsuitbreidingen, waaronder de laatste grachten van de fortificatie die nu als grachtengordel bekend is en in 2010 is toegevoegd aan de UNESCO-Werelderfgoedlijst.</p>

  <a class="button" href="https://www.buienradar.nl">Slecht weer</a>


</div>
```